# Tag for website-access issues

Tags: discussion

There are currently a handful of questions on the site about users who can't access certain websites (like [Yahoo](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/934/71) or [Facebook or YouTube](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/930/71)) when using Tor. Whether this is down to individual sites blocking Tor or [CloudFlare not playing nice](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/599/71) or just a random connection issue this will probably keep cropping up.

How should we handle these? Should each instance be its own question, or should we only allow one question of this type per website before marking duplicates? Should we even try to handle questions about website-specific issues that we may not be able to answer anyway?

If we do decide to allow these to be on-topic, what tag should be used for them? I was thinking something like <kbd>access</kbd> or <kbd>website-access</kbd> might be the closest but I don't know if either of those is clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming we can answer it (eg. we know that a certain site blocks traffic from known exit nodes, or we know that a site is simply showing a captcha due to exsessive abuse, etc.) I think we should. We might even make a question with a list of known troublesome sites and make it community wiki (or maybe a separate question for different kinds of blocking: intentional blocking of Tor, incidental blocking due to abuse, etc.)

I'm not sure about the tag; I'm with you, I can't think of anything more clear but am not sure if those two convey much information. Maybe someone else will have better ideas.

Comment: I like the Community Wiki, so much I went ahead and [created one](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/949/71)!

Comment: Wow, looks fantastic! Great job